# Rearranging legend order plotted using ggsurv for Kaplan Meier curves

Tags: r, graph, legend, survival-analysis, legend-properties

I plotted Kaplan Meier curves for my data which is for 6 different treatments namely:

1. 100Low
2. 30Low
3. 15Low
4. 100High
5. 30High
6. 15High

I want my legend to be in the sequence that I mentioned above however when I plot it gives me the legend as attached in the image.[image]

The code that I am using is as follows. Could someone help me out with how could I rearrange the order of the legend table?

```
    #Kaplan-Meier curves to plot the result
ru <- survfit(Surv(Tf,fat==1) ~ Treatments, data = fat)

uu <- ggsurv(ru, CI = "def", plot.cens = TRUE, surv.col = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
             cens.col = 1, lty.est = c(1,1,1,5,5,5), size.est = 1.05, cens.shape = 12, cens.size = 3,
             back.white = FALSE, xlab = "Time (seconds)", ylab = "Ratio of fish remaining", main = "Kaplan-Meier Curves")

uu1 <- uu + theme_gray(base_size=13) + theme(legend.position = "right") + theme(legend.title = element_text(face = "bold")) +
          theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold")) + theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_line(size = 1))  + scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)) + theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12))

windows()
(uu1)
```

**Here "Tf" is the time in my data which is in the data frame "fat"**

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reorder `Treatments` before your model, here a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

treat_order <- c("100Low","30Low","15Low","100High","30High","15High")

fat <-
    fat %>% 
    mutate(Treatments = fct_relevel(Treatments,treat_order))
```